# Is there a way to dynamically specify a queryset for nested relationship (nested serializer class) in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-rest-viewsets

Suppose we have two models:

```
class Chapter(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    body = models.TextField()
    is_archived = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    chapter = models.ForeignKey(Chapter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And default `ModelViewSet` viewset for `Chapter` model:

```
class ChapterViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Chapter.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ChapterSerializer
```

The key thing is that `ChapterSerializer` performs nested serialization using `PostSerializer` to provide a `post_set` key in the response.

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    detail_url = HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='post-detail', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'is_archived', 'detail_url']
        model = Post

class ChapterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    post_set = PostSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Chapter
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'owner', 'post_set']
```

The question is how I can dynamically specify a queryset for this nested `PostSerializer`. For example, when user makes `GET` request I only want to include the posts that are not archived (`is_archived` field is set to `False`) if user, who has done a request, is not an owner of a `Chapter` (`request.user != current_chapter.owner`). Is there any way to achive it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.prefetch_related) to prefetch the results used by a nested serializer, this prefetch can be filtered by using a [Prefetch](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch) object and this will then filter the nested results

```
class ChapterViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Chapter.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ChapterSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        return queryset.prefetch_related(
            Prefetch('post_set', queryset=Post.objects.filter(is_archived=False))
        )
```

In the `get_queryset` method you will have to perform this prefetching dynamically, the current request can be accessed via `self.request`

Comment: Thanks, this answer fully solves the problem.